# Show one product per category in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, categories, product

I have 6 main categories and 40 products per those categories in total. All of the products are displayed on the products link.

I need to display one (random) product per category so I have 6 displayed products in total.

I did some research but couldn't find any plugin for this.

Could anyone provide me with some tips on how can I resolve this?

Comment: If you try any code??Then please post your code here?Or else you can show me screenshot of what you need?

Comment: @developerme Hello. I would try any code, the thing is that I have no idea where should I try to change to code so I can get the desirable look. As I put as information, in the 'products' section all of the products are listed, i need to list one product per (main) category and have listed total number of products as the number of main categories. I'm not looking here for the whole solution, just tips on where should I start.